# specify server in sql script

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I am writing a sql script for sql server 2008 where I place a use statement at the beginning that specifies the database the script should be run against:

```
use [my_database]
```

As I have different environments where the same database exists, eg dev, qa, prod, is there any way I can specify in the script the environment the script is for, either by server name or ip address or by any other mechanism.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this question? Did @Filip De Vos's answer work for you?

Answer (score 31):

You can put the SQL Management Studio in [SQLCMD mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833281.aspx) and specify the server with the `:CONNECT myserver` statement.

You can switch on command mode by clicking on the option in the pic below
[image]

Your script would then look something like this

```
    :CONNECT devserver
    use [my_database]
    SELECT * FROM my_table
```

You can even make the query window switch servers during execution

```
    :CONNECT devserver
    use [my_database]
    SELECT * FROM my_table
    GO
    :CONNECT uatserver
    use [my_database]
    SELECT * FROM my_table
```

To connect with a specific user and password you can specify this as follows

```
    :CONNECT devserver -U myUser -P myPassword
    use [my_database]
    SELECT * FROM my_table
```

There are actually a number of options you can specify which are well [documented on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx).

Comment: Is there any way to do this and specify a user name and password? I am getting a login failed error.

Comment: you can do `:CONNECT devserver -U user -P password`. I will add it to the answer once my updates stop erroring.

Comment: Thanks . Is there a way to do this within nested / multiple cte? 
(for me this was better as I was locked out from linked servers)

Comment: no, this is a client hack, you can not embed it in queries.

Answer (score 1):

That's a **CONNECTION** setting, not a parameter within the script.

You can run the same script in different environments via batch file or powershell script if desired, or you could set up linked servers, but you can't just say

`USE SomeOtherServer`

There are security and networking implications as well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you will run all of these scripts on a particular server - e.g. the Dev server - then you merely need to create a Linked Server to each of the other servers.

Then, for example, you could run an identically named stored procedure on each of these servers thusly:

```
EXEC MyDatabase.dbo.mysp_DoSomething --Dev Server; no server prefix needed since that's where we are
EXEC QA.MyDatabase.dbo.mysp_DoSomething --QA Server
EXEC Prod.MyDatabase.dbo.mysp_DoSomething --Prod server
```

etc.